# how to write data into the excel sheet without erasing the previous data?

Tags: apache-poi

I tried the following code but not work properly.Any type of suggestion will be appreciated

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
 InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Read Data.xlsx");
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
 Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
 Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
 cell.setCellType(cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
 String cellContents = cell.getStringCellValue();
 //Modify the cellContents here
 // Write the output to a file
 //cell.setCellValue(cellContents); 
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Read Data.xlsx");
 sheet.createRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue(cellContents);
 wb.write(fileOut);
 fileOut.close();
 System.out.println(cellContents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("wb.xls");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt([sheet index]);
Row row = sheet.getRow([row index]);
Cell cell = row.getCell([cell index]);
String cellContents = cell.getStringCellValue(); 
//Modify the cellContents here
// Write the output to a file
cell.setCellValue(cellContents); 
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("wb.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are re-creating an existing row, which is wiping out the values already there:

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
....
sheet.createRow(1).createCell(1).setCellValue(cellContents);
```

The first call fetches the 2nd row, the second one wipes it and creates a new one

All you need to do is change the second one to re-use the already fetched existing row, and you'll keep the existing values!

Something like (with other fixes....):

```
 DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
 Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
 Cell cell = row.getCell(0);
 String cellContents = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

 //Modify the cellContents here

 row.createCell(1).setCellValue(cellContents);
 FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Read Data.xlsx");
 wb.write(fileOut);
 fileOut.close();
```